# Al clickear botón cancelar me redirija a otra URL con Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Para mis botones:

```
<w-button
            class="btn-cancel marginRight5"
            @click="Cancel">
            {{ i18nTexts.btnCancel }}
          </w-button>
            <w-button
              class="btn-confirm marginRight5"
              @click="Confirm">
              {{ i18nTexts.btnConfirm }}
</w-button>
```

Tengo la siguiente función para el botón de guardar que funciona:

```
async Confirm () {
      helperModal.showWindowContentLoading()
      let response = await ApiService.post('/config/updateExtraConfiguration', {
        google_tag_manager_code: 'GTM-123456' 
      });

      if (response.success) {
        this.messageManager.showSuccessMessage(this.translateText('Se han guardado correctamente los cambios.'))
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
        this.closeModal()
      } else {
        this.messageManager.showErrorMessage(this.translateText('No se han podido guardar los cambios. Intenta nuevamente.'))
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
      }
    }
```

Pero necesito saber como hacer con el botón cancelar que al hacer click, me lleve a esta ruta `(/marketing/applications)`.

Comment: ni siquiera necesitas `vue` para eso, al boton cancelar colocale `'onclick=location.href = '/marketing/applications' ` y listo'

Comment: usas vue-router ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según los documentos, router.push parece ser el método preferido:

> Para navegar a una URL diferente, use router.push. Este método inserta
>   una nueva entrada en la pila de historial, de modo que cuando el
>   usuario haga clic en el botón de retroceso del navegador, accederá a
>   la URL anterior.

fuente: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

```
this.$router
```

Ejemplo: si desea redirigir a una ruta llamada "Home"

```
this.$router.push('Home')
```

Según la respuesta de: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42464582/7332409

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por los comentarios, estaba trabado pero la solución era sencilla.

```
clickBtnCancel () {
      window.location.href = '/marketing/applications'
    },
```

Comment: Siempre para servirte.